# Константный двойной указатель

Tags: c++, указатели, const

Есть функция:

```
void Foo(int **ptr);
```

Хочется защитить данные в `ptr` от изменения, то есть сделать данные `ptr` константными. Если бы указатель был одинарный, можно было бы сделать так:

```
void Foo(const int *ptr);
```

Для двойного указателя я сделал так:

```
void Foo(const int **ptr);
```

Данные в ptr теперь действительно защищены, но в отличие от случая одинарного указателя, вызов вида:

```
int **ptr = /*pointer init*/;
Foo(ptr);
```

невозможен, пишет, что конвертация `int**` в `const int**` невозможна. Как исправить эту ситуацию, чтобы сохранить возможность конвертации и защитить данные в `ptr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявите функцию как

```
void Foo(const int *const *ptr);
```

В этом случае конвертация из `int **` станет возможной.

P.S. Это будет работать в С++. В C, к сожалению, хорошего решения нет и придется применять явное преобразование типов.

Comment: Но присваивание   int **ptr = Foo(ptr);   в любом случаи невозможно

Comment: Там имелось ввиду не присваивание, поправил вопрос, чтобы исключить двузначность.